# ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission and PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission always return 0?

Tags: android, permissions

When I use two ways to check `Android6.0` permissions:

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
```

and

```
PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(this, "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")
```

always return 0 ?

My targetSdkVersion is 23,  How do you break this problem?

Comment: Are you adding permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: 0 is PERMISSION_GRANTED, what's your problem? Below Android 6 they will always return 0 because you grant all permissions before installing the app.

Comment: i have been added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> in AndroidManifest.xml @Rafay Ali

Comment: @Eugen Pechanec , I refused permission after install the app , at this time should be unauthorized , Should‘t return zero